# Selenium Horizontal Scroll: Clicking Right Arrow Not Working

Tags: java, selenium, scrollbar

I have a horizontal scroll bar and I need to be able to click the next arrow / right arrow. I also have a vertical scroll bar and I was able to do clicking the down arrow using this code:

```
Point item =driver.findElement(By.className("z-biglistbox-wscroll-down")).getLocation();
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy("+(item.getY())+",0);");
actions.moveToElement(down).click().build().perform();
```

I was wondering if I can click the right arrow using the same code. I tried this but it's not working:

```
Point item =driver.findElement(By.className("z-biglistbox-wscroll-down")).getLocation();
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy("+ (item.getX()) +",0);");
actions.moveToElement(down).click().build().perform();
```

Any idea why this is not working?

[*Click here to see what the scroll bar looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TAbr.jpg)

This is the html of the horizontal scroll bar:

```
<div class="z-biglistbox-wscroll-drag" style="left: 0px;">
   <div class="z-biglistbox-wscroll-home" title="Home"></div>
   <div class="z-biglistbox-wscroll-up" title="Previous"></div>
   <div class="z-biglistbox-wscroll-down" title="Next"></div>
   <div class="z-biglistbox-wscroll-end" title="End"></div>
</div>
```

UPDATE:
I solved the problem using the code below. Seems like I just got the wrong combination of coordinates. Anyway, hope this helps someone in the future.

```
Point item =driver.findElement(By.xpath(rightkey)).getLocation();
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,"+(item.getY())+");");
actions.moveToElement(right).click().build().perform();
```

Comment: Getting error? show it.

Comment: Yes. This is the error: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.interactions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: (312.70001220703125, 1708.9000244140625) is out of bounds of viewport width (1920) and height (933)

Comment: Uh, the two code samples are the same.  Please show us the html that you are trying to interact with, and show us the code that isn't working with the horizontal bar?

Comment: and by the way, the class names of the horizontal and vertical scrollbar are the same